# Javascript class method binding not working

Tags: javascript

I have this class:

```js
class test{
    constructor(){
        document.addEventListener('click', handle);
        this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);
    }

    handle(){
        console.log(this); //returns document element
    }
}

new test()
```

I'm binding `this` to the handle event but it still returns the document element.
I tried using arrow functions and it works but I want to know if I can do it without using arrow functions...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nevermind, my local server was caching the JS file with the updated code

Comment: You should probably delete the question then

Comment: I was thinking of leaving it because maybe someone will make the same stupid mistake but maybe it's too broad and isn't worth leaving it

Comment: If there's a real question here then it's fine to keep it, but I'm not clear on what you were trying to do. Perhaps if you can clarify it in a way that doesn't make reference to your toolchain mistake? I'll remove my downvote if you can do that. At the very least this isn't an answer.

Comment: When the handle() method was firing, the document element was being passed to the method by the keyword "this", and I wanted "this" to reference the class instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assign before the binding.

You're thinking that a reference will be modified, however, you're only assigning a new value to that attribute rather than modifying it.

```js
class test {
  constructor() {
    this.eleFromEstack = "Test"; //  Just a test!
    this.handle = this.handle.bind(this);
    document.addEventListener('click', this.handle);
  }

  handle() {
    console.log(this);
  }
}

new test();
```

```html
<h1>Click!!</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `this` value when supplying the `handler` function to the `addEventListener` callback.

```js
class Test{
    field = "hello"
    handle(){
        console.log(this); //returns document element
    }
    constructor(){
        document.querySelector("#container").addEventListener('click', this.handle.bind(this));
       
    }
   
}
let test = new Test();
```

```html
<div id="container">test</div>
```